# Does std::vector.pop_back() change vector's capacity?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, memory-management

If I allocated an std::vector to a certain size and capacity using `resize()` and `reserve()` at the beginning of my program, is it possible that `pop_back()` may "break" the reserved capacity and cause reallocations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. The only way to shrink a vector's capacity is the swap trick

```
template< typename T, class Allocator >
void shrink_capacity(std::vector<T,Allocator>& v)
{
   std::vector<T,Allocator>(v.begin(),v.end()).swap(v);
}
```

and even that isn't guaranteed to work according to the standard. (Although it's hard to imagine an implementation where it wouldn't work.)

As far as I know, the next version of the C++ standard (what used to be C++0x, but now became C++1x) will have `std::vector<>::shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: I would very much advise against this trick for three reasons: 1. Function doesn't necessarily do what it says it does. 2 Breaks the principle of "least surprise" 3. Incurs a huge amount of overhead, potentially - not to mention potential side-effects of copying rather than moving.

Comment: @einpoklum: Yeah, this is without moving, and thus suboptimal today. But this answer is almost a decade old, so...

Comment: @sbi: I would advise against it then as well :-(

Comment: @einpoklum: So you would, huh? Well, the C++ community thought otherwise back then. So go figure.

Answer (score 4):

No. pop_back() will not shrink the capacity of vector. use 
`std::vector<T>(v).swap(v)` instead.

Comment: Duplicate of @sbi's answer; and see my comment there about the "swap trick".

Answer (score 4):

Under C++11 one can call shrink_to_fit() to ask for a vector (as well as a deque or a string) in order to reduce the reserved space to the vector's capacity. Note however that this is implementation dependent: it's merely a request and there's no guarantee whatsoever. You can try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> myVector;

    for (auto i=1;i!=1e3;++i)
        myVector.push_back(i);

    cout << "Capacity: " << myVector.capacity() << endl;
    myVector.reserve(2000);
    cout << "Capacity (after reserving 2000): " << myVector.capacity() << endl;
    myVector.shrink_to_fit();
    cout << "Capacity (after shrink_to_fit): " << myVector.capacity(); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

NO. Same as `push_back` , `pop_back` won't impact the `capacity()`. They just impact the `size()`.

EDIT:

I should have said `push_back` won't change the capacity when the `v.size() < v.capacity()`.

Answer (score 2):

pop_XXX will never change the capacity.  push_XXX can change the capacity if you try to push more stuff on than the capacity allows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code of std::vector::pop_back()

```
void pop_back()
{   // erase element at end
   if (!empty())
   {    // erase last element
      _Dest_val(this->_Alval, this->_Mylast - 1);
      --this->_Mylast;
   }
}
```

Function only calls the Destructor and decreases pointer to the last element.
Code from VC (Release). So it does not affect on capacity (or reallocation) of vector.

Comment: One particular implementation isn't enough information to determine what the standard requires.  And this may not be the same implementation that the person asking the question uses.