# Can I create an anonymous, brace-initialized aggregate in C++?

Tags: c++, aggregate, initializer

One can create an anonymous object that is initialized through constructor parameters, such as in the return statement, below.

```
struct S {
  S(int i_, int j_) : i(i_), j(j_) { }
  int i, j;
};

S f()
{
  return S(52, 100);
}

int main()
{
  cout << f().i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However, can one similarly create an anonymous *aggregate* that is initialized with a brace initializer? For example, can one collapse the body of f(), below, down to a single return statement without an "s?"

```
struct S {
  int i, j;
};

S f()
{
  S s = { 52, 100 };
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  cout << f().i << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dang, looks like the answer is going to be, no...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't in the current version of C++. You will be able to in C++ 0x -- I believe anyway. Of course, it's still open to revision -- at one time I believed you'd be able to specify concepts in C++ 0x, but that's gone...

Edit: The reference would be [dcl.init] (§8.5/1) in [N2960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf). The most relevant bit is the definition of 'braced-init-list' in the BNF (and the last bit of text, saying that the initialization described in that section can/does apply to return values).

Comment: +1 @Jerry. Right, but it is in §8.5.4/1. You missed a number.

Comment: §8.5/1 was the part I was looking at (and gives enough to answer the current question). You're right, however, that §8.5.4/1 is what covers braced initializer lists specifically, and it has a lot more detail about them.

Answer (score 5):

Not in C++.  But you can in C99, using so-called *compound literals*:

```
struct S {
  int i, j;
};

struct S F()
{
  // Valid C99, invalid C++:
  return (struct S){ 52, 100 };
}
```

[C99: §6.5.2, 6.5.2.5]
[C++98: §5.2.3, 8.5, 12.1, 12.2]

Some C++ compilers provide this as an extension, but it's not legal ISO C++98.  For example, g++ will accept this code by default, but if you compile with the `-pedantic` option, it will reject it.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to use brace initialization just about everywhere in C++1x. (Although Comeau 4.3.9 alpha chokes on fnieto's example.)

Comment: @sbi: even though it won't be out this year, for the sake of everybody's sanity, it's probably best to still call is C++ 0x. As you should expect with '0x' as the prefix, the digit will be in hexadecimal.
@frieto: you were right. Draft cited above...

Comment: @Jerry: Please read my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536753/1536779#1536779.