# Keeping constant number of elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to figure out the fastest way to keep constant number of elements in vector (or maybe there is some ready-made structure that do it automatically).

In my app I am adding multiple elements to the vector and I need to do it fast. Because of vector's self resizing at some point it is significantly decreasing overall application speed. What I was thinking about is to do something like this:

```
if(my_vector.size() < 300)
    my_vector.push_back(new_element);
else
{
    my_vector.pop_front();
    my_vector.push_back(new_element);
}
```

but after first few tests I've realized that it might not be the best solution, because I am not sure if `pop_front()` and later `push_back()` doesn't still need to resize at some point.

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: IIRC it resizes when the count goes over a power of 2.

Comment: You can use `std::array` if you know the size of elements you want. Or even better use and `std::deque` which is optimized for front/back insertion/removal and always check the `size()` before anything you do.

Comment: @Carlos Because in my case I have 100s of those vectors even if half is resizing it is taking significant number of time.

Comment: @GeorgeAl `std::array` is not best here, because I know how many elements I want to have, but not how many I'll have. As for `std::deque` I might try this, now when I think about it. If I remember it correctly if I'll remove first element it will start next time reading from second - is that correct?

Comment: You can keep your vector a constant size and when you reach your size limit just swap the value for that position e.g.: `my_vector[299] = new_element` you wouldn't need to `pop`, also `pop`ing doesn't cause a reallocation

Comment: @EdChum in this case I am swapping n-th element, but when I am reading it in order, then I have mess, so I cannot do it like that.

Comment: Take a look at [boost::circular](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Comment: Reopened. This question is **not** about FIFO, but about **fixed size**. That's a completely different animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a fixed-size container with push_back and pop_front and **minimal** memory shuffling, use a `std::array` of the appropriate size. To keep track of things you'll need a front index for pushing elements and a back index for popping things. To push, store the element at the location given by `front_index`, then increment `front_index` and take the remainder modulo the container size. To pop, read the element at the location given by `back_index`, and adjust that index the same way you did `front_index`. With that in place, the code in the question will do what you need.

Comment: Your idea really makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `std::queue`. Its underlying container is a `std::deque`, but like a stack a queue's interface is specifically for FIFO operations (push_back, pop_front), which is exactly what you're doing in your situation. Here's why a deque is better for this situation:

> The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as
>   needed. Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a
>   std::vector because it does not involve copying of the existing
>   elements to a new memory location.
>
> The complexity (efficiency) of common operations on deques is as
>   follows:
>
> - Random access - constant O(1)
> - Insertion or removal of elements at the end or beginning - constant O(1)

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that `pop_front` is the really slow operation in a `vector`. We need a structure with good `pop_front()` performance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `reserve` the capacity to a reasonable number. The vector will not automatically [shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536753/3344612). So it only will grow and, possibly, stop at some point.

You might be also interested in the resize policies. For example Facebook made a substantial research and created own implementation of the vector - [`folly::fbvector`](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md) which has better performance than `std::vector`